# restrict ssh access to /bin and using bash as a shell

Tags: bash, chroot, openssh

I want to restrict my admin user to /bin directory while permitting to use bash as a shell via ssh.
This is in my sshd_config file:

```
Match User admin    
   ChrootDirectory /bin
   X11Forwarding no
   ForceCommand scponly
   #PermitTunnel no
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

in `/etc/passwd`:

```
 admin:x:1001:100:,,,:/:/bash
```

when I use this command: 
     ssh admin@192.168.1.20

this error appears:

```
 /bash: No such file or directory
 Connection to 192.168.200.242 closed.
```

if I change scponly to internal-sftp in sshd_config, all binary files exist (for example, bash) in / directory via sftp. Why I can't use `/bash` as a shell after changing to `scponly`?

How can I get this to work.

Comment: The authentication process and retrieval of user information such as the shell is done prior to any chrooting (basically, PAM happens before sshd).

Comment: Ok, but if i change to /bin/bash, the same error occurs. how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Run `ldd /bin/bash` . All those shared libraries need to be available in the chrooted environment to run that command.

Comment: That's right ...Thank you very much Mark.